# reverse string without array function

Tags: c#, console-application

hi i am trying string reverse with out using array method

```
        string input = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter string wants to reverse");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        char[] inputarray = input.ToCharArray();
        string reverse =string.Empty;
        for (int i = inputarray.Length - 1; i <= inputarray.Length ; i--)
        {
            reverse += inputarray[i];

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reverse string {0}", reverse);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

i miss something on for loop.. what is that?? i can' t find..

Comment: You miss the fact that i should go to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second section in loop is wrong i always less than  inputarray.Length. Try

```
for (int i = inputarray.Length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
```

Comment: this solution is marked as an answer but it's clearly wrong. it should be >=0 instead of >0

Answer (score 0):

Try using substring function....instead of getting a character array of the string........get characters one by one from the end using substring

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin method "reverse" on string. If you really want to do that this way then your condition in a loop is wrong.
change `i <= inputarray.Length` to `i>=0`

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Malathi
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string input = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter string wants to reverse");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            char[] inputarray = input.ToCharArray();
            string reverse = string.Empty;
            for (int i = inputarray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                reverse += inputarray[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Reverse string {0}", reverse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```